# Thumbnail of video from Google Photos cloud

Tags: android

Is there any way to show thumbnail of video from Google Photos URI, which isn't stored local? I managed to display picture by create input stream from URI, and pass it to BitmapFactory. But with videos situation seems to be a bit more complicated. Right now I found one working scenario and it is downloading video, and then load photo from local file, which of course from user's point of view isn't option.

Example of Google Photos URI: content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/0/2/mediakey%3A%2Flocal%*guid*/ORIGINAL/NONE/*id*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22855053/generate-thumbnail-from-server-video-link-android